# Can $I[[X]] = I\cdot R[[X]]$ if $I$ is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, power-series

Let $R$ be a ring and $R[[X]]$ be the formal power series ring. For any ideal $I\subset R$, denote by $I[[X]]$ the ideal of power series with coefficients in $I$.

If $I$ is finitely generated, it is clear that $I\cdot R[[X]]=I[[X]]$. Instead, *if $I$ is not finitely generated, is it possible that $I\cdot R[[X]]=I[[X]]$?*

If $I$ has a countable set of generators, say $\{i_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, the power series $$F:=\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}i_nX^n$$ is in  $I\cdot R[[X]]$ if and only if $I$ is finitely generated; hence *if $I$ is not finitely generated, but countably generated, holds $I\cdot R[[X]]\subsetneq I[[X]]$.*

But is there some not countably generated ideal $I$ of a ring $R$, such that $I\cdot R[[X]]=I[[X]]$? Thanks for your help

Comment: For first question, I think the answer is no. Your post already has the answer. Consider the following ring $R=k[x_1,x_2,....]$ with ideal $I=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$. Then a valid element of $I[[T]]$ is $1+x_1T+x_2T^2+\dots$

Meanwhile, $I\cdot R[[T]]$  cannot contain this element. The issue is that although this ideal will contains parts of this power series, it cannot contain all of it.

For noncountably generated, the answer seems to be no once more? You could just do the same trick.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician the power series needs to start with $x_1$ as a constant term. Otherwise it's not in $I[[T]]$. Also, in which way does your comment answer the question? I think you misunderstood it. We are looking for a non-finitely generated ideal where the equality holds. In your example, the equality does not hold.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah yes, my bad. But I think the point of my example stands.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician sorry I don't really see your point. You gave an example of a countably but not finitely generated ideal $I$ for which $I\cdot R[[T]]\subsetneq I[[T]]$; but I already proved that this is always the case

Comment: @JerryScott My apologies, I answered the question you had in the title. I dod not see your last question at the bottom.

Comment: The answer is yes, see e.g. [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-21/issue-3/Some-countability-conditions-in-a-commutative-ring/10.1215/ijm/1256049016.full)

Comment: @math54321 I have added the ref to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I\cdot R[[X]]=I[[X]]$ holds if and only if every countable subset of $I$ is contained in a finitely generated ideal inside of $I$. (The proof of the equivalence is easy.)

If $I$ is countably generated, this property clearly implies that $I$ is finitely generated (as you have noticed).

But in general we cannot deduce this. *Sketch.* Imagine having a ring with elements $(x_{\alpha})$ for all countable ordinals $\alpha$, and also elements $y_{\alpha,\beta}$ for $\alpha < \beta$ satisfying $x_{\alpha} = x_{\beta} \cdot y_{\alpha,\beta}$. Then for all $\beta$ we have $\langle x_{\alpha} : \alpha < \beta \rangle \subseteq \langle x_{\beta} \rangle$.

*Edit.* A counterexample appears in [Rings of formal power series over a Krull domain](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01115087) by Gilmer and Heinzer. This is mentioned in [Some countability conditions in a commutative ring](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-21/issue-3/Some-countability-conditions-in-a-commutative-ring/10.1215/ijm/1256049016.full) by Arnold, Gilmer, Heinzer, where ideals with that property are studied in general.

PS: The question has been asked before at [SE/4556458](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556458) but I am not convinced of the accepted answer there.

Comment: Does anybody have access to the article by Gilmer and Heinzer and maybe can add the example?

Comment: From Gilmer and Heinzer paper: "We remark that the equality A[[X]] = AR[[X]] need not imply that A is finitely generated. For example, if R is a valuation ring whose set of prime ideals is of ordinal type O, the first un- countable ordinal, then each countable subset of A, the maximal ideal of R, is contained in a finitely generated ideal contained in A, but A itself is not finitely generated."